# how to make a nav bar seamless to status bar?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've been trying to change the color of the status bar to be the same as the nav bar in my Swift project, and can't for the life of me figure out how to do it. The closest I've come is by placing a long, thin view behind the status bar, and then changing it to match the nav bar color as close as possible. Ive seen this done in many apps before, and would love to know how it's done.

Thanks in advance!

[desired style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kdWt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add this key in plist and set it to NO
   `View controller-based status bar appearance`
2. in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

   ```
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: false)
   ```
3. Set up navigationBar in `viewDidLoad`

   ```
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor .blueColor()
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
   ```
4. Set navigationBar TitleColor to white

Then it looks like

[image]

Comment: That didn't actually work for me. Does the view need to be embedded in a Navigation Controller?